# Display specific image depending on specific text in MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my MySQL database I have table named `game` with columns: `sport_cat`, `timelive`, `match_title`, `selection`,

I am exactly this MySQL query SELECT statement for displaying them in grid view on site:

```
<?
$qry = "
SELECT sport_cat,match_title,selection,
CASE 
WHEN game.result LIKE '' THEN 'PENDING'
WHEN game.result LIKE game.selection THEN 'WON'
WHEN game.result NOT LIKE game.selection THEN 'LOST'
END AS result
FROM game
";
$searchText = "";
if($_REQUEST['search_text']!=""){
$searchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['search_text']);
$qry .=" WHERE sport_cat.timelive LIKE '%$searchText%' " . 
       " OR game.timelive LIKE '%$searchText%' " .
       " OR game.match_title LIKE '%$searchText%' ";      
}

$qry .= " ORDER BY timelive DESC";

$obj = new pagination_class($qry,$starting,$recpage);       
$result = $obj->result;

?>
```

In first column `sport_cat` there are few possible text inputs: `football`, `tennis`, `basketball`.

HTML of my file where this part is looks like this:

```
<table>
<?if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0){
$counter = $starting + 1;
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
<tr>
<td align="center"><? echo $data['sport_cat']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><? echo $data['timelive']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><? echo $data['match_title']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><? echo $data['selection']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?
$counter ++;
} ?>
</table>
```

What I am trying to do is to display specific picture in those cell according to that input in cell. So if there is `football` want to display `football.png` picture or if there is `tennis` want to display `tennis.png` or if there is `basketball` want to display `basketball.png`.
Also, if there is maybe some unknown input like `cricket` and don't have picture specified for that word would like to display `unknown.png` picture.
Pictures are stored under `images/icons` on my server.

Now i'm not sure how to implement this code regarding picturing issue into this already existent i have. 
Thanks.

ADDED full example code: 03.11.2011.:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
include('pagination_class.php');
mysql_connect('xxx.xxx.xxx.xx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('xxxxxxx');

?>
<script language="JavaScript" src="pagination.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<?
$qry = "
SELECT sport_cat,bidprice,timelive,match_title,selection,winnings_with_startamount,odds,odds*10 AS gainedodds,username,
CASE 
WHEN game.result LIKE '' THEN 'pending'
WHEN game.result LIKE game.selection THEN 'WON'
WHEN game.result NOT LIKE game.selection THEN 'LOST'
END AS result
FROM game
";
$searchText = "";
if($_REQUEST['search_text']!=""){
$searchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['search_text']);
$qry .=" WHERE game.sport_cat LIKE '%$searchText%' " . 
       " OR game.timelive LIKE '%$searchText%' " .
       " OR game.match_title LIKE '%$searchText%' " .
       " OR game.selection LIKE '%$searchText%' " .
       " OR game.username LIKE '%$searchText%'";
}

$qry .= " ORDER BY timelive DESC";

//for pagination
$starting=0;
$recpage = 10;//number of records per page

$obj = new pagination_class($qry,$starting,$recpage);       
$result = $obj->result;


function getStyleColorForStatus($status) {
  if ($status == 'WON') {
    return '#99ff99';
  }
  else if ($status == 'LOST') {
    return '#ff9999';
  }
  else if ($status == 'pending') {
    return '#e5e5e5';
  }
  return '';
}

?>

        <form name="form1" action="testpage.php" method="POST" style="background-color:#f9f9f9; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1); box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);">

        <table border="0" align="center" width="1000px" padding-left="0px" style="background:#F9F9F9;">

          <TD colspan="0" style="padding-left:0px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:10px; text-align:center;">
            Search: <input type="text" name="search_text" value="<?php echo $searchText; ?>">
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
          </TD> 

        <tr><TD colspan="0">

        <div id="page_contents">

            <table width="968px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center" frame="box" rules="none" style="padding-bottom:20px; margin-bottom:8px;margin-top:3px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1); box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1); border: 1px solid #cccccc;">
            <tr style="height: 50px;">
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Event Category</div></td></td>
<td width="5%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Bid Cost</div></td></td>
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Event Start Time</div></td></td>
<td width="35%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Market/Event</div></td></td>
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Selection</div></td></td>
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Winnings</div></td></td>
<td width="5%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Odds</div></td></td>
<td width="5%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Gained Odds</div></td></td>
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Winning Bidder</div></td></td>
<td width="10%" align="center" td class="winheader"><div class="glowtext">Final Result</div></td></td>
            </tr>
            <?
            if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0){
                $counter = $starting + 1;
                $pathImg = "/images/icons/";
                while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    //calculate url image
                    $pathFile = $pathImg . $data['sport_cat'] . ".png";
                    if (!file_exists($pathFile)) {
                        $pathFile = $pathImg . "unknown.png";
                    }
                    ?>

    <tr class="initial" onMouseOver="this.className='highlight'" onMouseOut="this.className='normal'">

                    <td align="center"><img src="<?=$pathFile?>" alt="<?=$data['sport_cat']?>"></TD>
                    <td align="center"><? echo $data['bidprice']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center"><? echo $data['timelive']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="left"><? echo $data['match_title']; ?></TD>              
                    <td align="left"><? echo $data['selection']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center"><font color="green">&euro; <? echo $data['winnings_with_startamount']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center"><? echo $data['odds']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center"><? echo $data['gainedodds']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center"><? echo $data['username']; ?></TD>
                    <td align="center" style="background-color:<?php echo getStyleColorForStatus($data['result']); ?>"><? echo $data['result']; ?></td>
                    </tr>

                <?
                    $counter ++;
                } 
            }
        ?>

                <tr><TD align="center" colspan="10" style="padding-bottom:1px; padding-top:10px; color:#333;"><? echo $obj->anchors; ?></TD></tr>
                <tr><TD align="center" colspan="10" style="padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:5px; color:#333;"><? echo $obj->total; ?></TD></tr>
            <?}else{?>
                <tr><TD align="center" colspan="10" style="padding-bottom:10px padding-top:10px; color:red;">No Data Found</TD></tr>
            <?}?>
            </TD></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </tr>
        </TD>
    </form>
    </table>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. We can help fix that. But we won't write it from scratch for you. This is a "please help" site, not "please do it for me"

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM game";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$pathImg = "/images/icons/";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $pathFile = $pathImg . $row['sport_cat'] . ".png";
    if (!file_exists($pathFile)) {
        $pathFile = $pathImg . "unknown.png";
    }
    echo '<img src="' . $pathFile . '">';
}
```

---

### You edit Ask and I edit Anwer :P

```
<table>
    <?
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
        $counter = $starting + 1;
        $pathImg = "/images/icons/";
        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            //calculate url image
            $pathFile = $pathImg . $data['sport_cat'] . ".png";
            if (!file_exists($pathFile)) {
                $pathFile = $pathImg . "unknown.png";
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><img src="<?=$pathFile?>" alt="<?=$data['sport_cat']?>"></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $data['sport_cat']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $data['timelive']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $data['match_title']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $data['selection']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, now I see I didn't explain well my question as cannot use this code in my case, so now modified it with more details...

Comment: Argh! @JellyBelly cannot get it work with your code, just receiving Server Error when adding this code on file. So added more code at my question which I have there to clearly explain better problem. Added HTML part of code so please take a look! other html having there i think is not important. Thanks for patience, I am total beginner.

Comment: @Ivy: I edit my answer! Before you received a fatal error because I thought he was already an array `$result` however was still undergoing treatment `mysql_fetch_array`! :D

Comment: To @JellyBelly: again just receiving **Server error** after your last modification :( Now in my initial question at the end of post I put copy/paste of whole file code just to be sure. Please take a look now on my answer continuation above to see for sure what is wrong there and to make it work.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice your answer here before! Here is error received in Chrome: `HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.`

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM game";
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
// Show images

if($row['sport_cat']=='football'){
 print "<img src='football.png'/>";
}
elseif($row['sport_cat']=='basketball'){
 print "<img src='basketball.png'/>";
}
elseif($row['sport_cat']=='tennis'){
 print "<img src='tennis.png'/>";
}else{
 print "<img src='unknown.png' />";
}


} // End while loop
?>
```

Comment: Hi Scott. Thanks for reply. Could you try to modify this according to my edited question above now? Sorry, I didn't explain right first time :(