# Display specific image when a file is missing

Tags: php, mysql, image, display

I'm a beginner to coding and need a little help. I have a code that shows an image according to a specific value in a column of a MySQL table like this:

```
//Show last 10 added by ID
$sql = "(SELECT * FROM food_tbl ORDER BY food_id DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY food_id ASC;";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$pathImg = "/images/";
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $pathFile = $pathImg . $row['food_name'] . ".jpg";
        echo '<img src="' . $pathFile . '">';
    }
}
```

This outputs, for example, banana.jpg ... The thing is... I would like to show a standard image when files don't actually exist, as in, if I don't have a file called banana.jpg in my "/images/" directory it would show a unknownfood.jpg file instead (which would indeed be inside that directory of course).

Now, here's the thing, I've already found some stuff over here: --- [Display specific image depending on specific text in MySQL table using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981957/display-specific-image-depending-on-specific-text-in-mysql-table-using-php)

... and I ended up trying this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pathFile = $pathImg . $row['food_name'] . ".jpg";
    if (file_exists($pathFile)) {
        echo '<img src="' . $pathFile . '">';
    } else {
    $pathFile = $pathImg . "unknownfood.jpg";
    echo '<img src="' . $pathFile . '">';
    }
}
```

Now, what this does is this will completely ignore the files that are actually there. For example, if I try showing banana.jpg it will instead show unknownfood.jpg.

I'm pretty sure it's something really easy that I'm screwing up, or something I'm not using the way it's intended to. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what do you store in your row if there is not image? null?

Comment: @MarkNg I have to update daily and I could end up having to add a new value for "food_name", but the images used need to be very specific so it may take a while to actually have them up the same day I have to add a new value. So the point of this is to have a "pending" image file kind of thing (the format used in the site NEEDS an image that's why I need to add a placeholder image) while I actually set up a proper one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in PHP, using `file_exists($pathFile)` is the path on the server, relative to the document root (which could be `/public_html/youruser`), while the HTML reads from the base-folder (off the domain, `/`).

This means your code would have to look something like this

```
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$pathFile))
```

Comment: Whoa that's it. Very grateful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists` will check a filesystem path, for example `/home/www/images/banana.jpg`.

When you display the `img` tag, it will pull the image from the doc root, `domain.com/images/banana.jpg`.

Find the correct file system path and pass it to `file_exists`, it will return the correct answer.

Right now it will always return false so you will end up in the `else` part of the `if` clause.